# Cannot read property 'openDatabase' of undefined en android

Tags: android, ionic, sqlite, cordova, ng-cordova

Tratando de gestionar una base de datos en el dispositivo a través de el plugin que facilita **ngCordova**, me he encontrado con el siguiente error, y no se sinceramente la razón. El dispositivo posee android 4.2.2

#### Error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'openDatabase' of undefined
```

#### Modulo

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])
        .run(startApp)
        .controller('networkCtrl', networkCtrl)
        .factory('databaseFtr', databaseFtr);
```

#### Inicio App

```
startApp.$inject = ['$ionicPlatform'];

function startApp($ionicPlatform) {

    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

        if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
        }

        if (window.StatusBar) {
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }

    });

}
```

#### Controller

```
networkCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'databaseFtr'];

function networkCtrl($scope, databaseFtr) {
    databaseFtr.crearDB();
}
```

#### Factory

```
databaseFtr.$inject = ['$cordovaSQLite'];

function databaseFtr($cordovaSQLite) {

    return {

        crearDB: function() {

            var db;

            db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({
                name: "mydata.db",
                location: 'default'
            });


        }

    }

}
```

#### Captura de pantalla mostrando el plugin instalado en el proyecto

[image: imagen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pude resolver el problema indagando directamente en el repositorio del plugin en **GitHub**. El problema radica en que no se puede crear y abrir la base de datos al mismo tiempo que se ejecuta la aplicacion, ya qu entonces, al leer el método de abrir la **DB** que en este caso es `openDB`, este no sera reconocido a pesar de tener el plugin instalado.

La forma en que solucione el problema que se me presento es, solo crear y abrir la base de datos a través d la utilización de un evento click, como lo expondre en el siguiente código.

#### Código

```
function networkCtrl($scope, databaseFtr) {

    $scope.dbProcesos = {

        dbCreate: function() {
            var db;
            db = databaseFtr.crearDB();
        }

}




function databaseFtr($cordovaSQLite) {

    return {

        crearDB: function() {

            var db;

            db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({
                name: "patologias.db",
                location: 'default'
            });

            return db;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba reinstalando el plugin y escribiendo el siguiente comando en la terminal para refrescar los plugins:

```
ionic platform update android
```

Ya nos cuentas¡

Comment: No, en realidad encontré la solución, y se trata que no puede iniciar la base de datos al mismo tiempo que la app se esta iniciando, por que genera el error.