# Problema con la conexión de ionic v1 y SQlite

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic, sqlite

Estimados, he tenido algunos problemas para poder realizar la conexion con SQlite, es mi primer proyecto y he googleado harto, pero no logro dar con el problema, la consola me indica el siguiente error:
**

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'openDatabase' of undefined

testSQlite.js

```
var db = null;
angular.module("app.controllers",[

    'ionic',
    'ngCordova.plugins.sqlite',
    'ngCordova'
])
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
     console.log("cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);");
}
if(window.StatusBar) {
  StatusBar.styleDefault();
  console.log("StatusBar.styleDefault();");
}
});
})

.controller("testSQliteController",function($scope,$ionicPlatform,$timeout){
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    $timeout(function() {         

    db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "mydata.db",location: '?'});

    $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST people (id integer primary key, firstname text, lastname text)");

    }, 3000);

    if (ionic.Platform.isIOS() || ionic.Platform.isIPad()) {
            db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({ name: 'mydata.db', location: 'default' });
    } else {
            db = window.openDatabase("mydata.db", '1.0', 'people', 1024 * 1024 * 100);
    }
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        console.log("people created");
        var query = "INSERT INTO people (firstname, lastname) VALUES (?,?)";

        tx.executeSql(query, ["people", 100],
            function(res) {
            console.log("insertId: " + JSON.stringify(res));
            },
            function (err) {
            console.log(err);
            }
        );
    })
 })
});
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Creo saber cual es el problema, y este radica, en que se supone que la base de datos no existe al momento de correr la aplicacion, en tu caso, la tienes en el **run**, entonces, cuando la app inicia, no encuentra la bd por que no existe.

Si lo que quieres es que ocurra esto, como para probar que esta funcionando bien, haz lo siguiente.

```
$timeout(function() {         

  db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "mydata.db",location: '?'});

  $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST people (id integer primary key, firstname text, lastname text)");

}, 3000);
```

El código anterior, lo puedes colocar dentro del controller inicial, o donde tu quieras, pero lo que va a pasar, es que, solo se iniciar lo de abrir a bd e insertar los datos, luego de que ese tiempo halla pasado, o sea, luego que la aplicacion inicio, y así no se genera dicho error.

Por otra parte, te recomiendo cambiar la forma en que estas creando la BD, y es por experiencia propia, no se sobre que versión de andrid estas probando, pero he visto que versiones con android 5.0 hacia arriba, me genera el problema de que los datos no se insertan en la base de datos, no genera ningún error, pero tampoco los guarda.

```
var db;

if (ionic.Platform.isIOS() || ionic.Platform.isIPad()) {
            db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({ name: 'dbname.db', location: 'default' });
        } else {
            db = window.openDatabase("dbname.db", '1.0', 'nombre', 1024 * 1024 * 100);
        }
```

De igual forma, aquí te dejare una enlace a una pregunta, exactamente igual que hice yo un tiempo atrás, y por cosas del destino, me toco a mi mismo experimentar ciertas cosas.

Bueno, revisando tu código de nuevo, pude encontrar el problema, es que no estas pasando la función, asociado al plugin de `SQLite` de ngCordova, por nde razon cualquier cosa que quieras hacer no te va funcionar. Entonces debes pasar como parametro lo siguiente en el controller

```
 $cordovaSQLite

.controller("testSQliteController",function($scope, $ionicPlatform, $timeout,  $cordovaSQLite){
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    $timeout(function() {         

    db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "mydata.db",location: '?'});

    $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST people (id integer primary key, firstname text, lastname text)");

    }, 3000);

    if (ionic.Platform.isIOS() || ionic.Platform.isIPad()) {
            db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({ name: 'mydata.db', location: 'default' });
    } else {
            db = window.openDatabase("mydata.db", '1.0', 'people', 1024 * 1024 * 100);
    }
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        console.log("people created");
        var query = "INSERT INTO people (firstname, lastname) VALUES (?,?)";

        tx.executeSql(query, ["people", 100],
            function(res) {
            console.log("insertId: " + JSON.stringify(res));
            },
            function (err) {
            console.log(err);
            }
        );
    })
 })
});
```

[enlace problema con sqlite al iniciar la bd](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/40286/cannot-read-property-opendatabase-of-undefined-en-android)

Comment: he implementado lo que me comentas, actualizare la pregunta porque aun me aparece error

Comment: alli lo tienes, ya vi el otro problema, o mas bien el principal, te recomiendo cambiar la forma como estas creando la bd por que la te puse en la respuesta primero, créeme te vas a ahorrar un montón de dolores de cabezas mas adelante.

Answer (score 0):

el plugin que estaba usando no estaba actualizado, entonces se limpio el proyecto y se agrego el actualizado:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-plugin
```

en la consola te pedira dos confiraciones, le das "Y" a ambas , luego en el código puse lo siguiente:

FormSQlite.js

```
angular.module("app.controllers")
.controller("FormularioSQliteController",function($scope, $cordovaSQLite, $ionicPlatform){

$scope.titulo = "Formulario Test SQLite";

if (window.cordova) {
   db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({ name: "my.db" }); //device
        console.log("Android");
 }
 else{
        console.log("browser");
        //crearData();
        leerData();
 }

function crearData(){

   var db = window.openDatabase("my.db", '1', 'my', 1024 * 1024 * 100); // browser

    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DemoTable (name, score)');
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DemoTable VALUES (?,?)', ['Pedro', 101]);
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DemoTable VALUES (?,?)', ['Pablo', 202]);
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DemoTable VALUES (?,?)', ['Andres', 202]);
        }, function(error) {
                console.log('Transaction ERROR: ' + error.message);
            }, function() {
                console.log('Populated database OK');
        });
    }

function leerData(){
   var db = window.openDatabase("my.db", '1', 'my', 1024 * 1024 * 100); // browser
   var data = "";

   db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM DemoTable', 
                [],
                function(tx, results)
                {
                    console.log("SELECT OK");
                    var len = results.rows.length; 
                    console.log("Length ",len);

                    for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
                        data = results.rows.item(i)['name'] + '-' + results.rows.item(i)['score']
                        console.log("data", data);
                    }
                },
                function(tx, error)
                {
                    console.log("SELECT ERROR -->error:"+error);
                }
            );
        });
    }
}
);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]